# PT100 and MAX31865 readings showing wrong

Tags: arduino-uno, temperature-sensor, temperature

I am using PT100 (3 Wire) to measure the temperature with Arduino Uno and MAX31865. 
I have connected everything perfectly.
Configuration in the code i am using is :

```
max1.begin(MAX31865_3WIRE);
```

And the output is:

**output**

```
RTD value: 0 
Ratio = 0.00000000
Resistance = 0.00000000
Temperature = -242.02
```

I am testing it in a room temperature.

My question is , is there any settings or calibration that i need to do, or any other way to test the PT100 sensor, because the temperature is showing correct readings ?

Comment: I had the same problem and was solved due to the comment of fshero (Jun 3 at 11:35) about a capacitor wich drops the voltage on PIN 20 of the MAX31865.
I have logged in just to highlight the solution. Thanks fshero!!

Comment: I've the same problem with my shields;
Where is the componant to remove on the shield to solve the problem?
a picture of the modification is welcome thanks a lot
fabien

Answer (score 3):

I nearly have the same problem. I use five of the MAX31865-Boards with 2-Wire Termocouples on an Arduino Nano. Two of the five boards are working perfectly. The other 3 boards show exactly the same wrong behaviour you described. My temperature readings are exactly like yours (-242.02).

But I think I found the reason for the not working ones: The two working boards I bought on Amazon. The other three not working boards I bought on AliExpress. Maybe I (and maybe you too) got really bad fakes from China and they are simply dead :(

*(BTW: If I remove one working board from the SPI bus and read out the temperature with the arduino, I get also the value of -242.02. This value seems to be an error value in the Adafruit MAX31865 library)*

**EDIT: Fixed it with a workaround!Like shown in the picture below, simply remove the wrong component (SMD Capacitor) and create a solder bridge . See comments for more informations!**

Here is a picture of my modification of one chinese board as requested by the comments:

[image: Modification of the chinese MAX31865 driver board]

(It's not the best solution, but it works. For final using you should get the right filter ferrite and solder it on the board!)

Comment: I figured out the source of the error in my case: After some "debug measuring" with a multimeter I recognized, that the voltage of the VDD Pin of the Sensor is too low (1.6V but 3.3V are required)! **It seems the chinese version has a capacitor at the place, where a originally a filter ferrite should be** (see part FB1
 at [adafruit_products_schem.png](https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/assets/assets/000/037/310/original/adafruit_products_schem.png?1479237642)). This causes the voltage drop. I removed the capacitor and replaced it with a solder bridge. Et voilá. It's working perfectly! :D

Comment: If wanted, I can provide some pictures of my modification

Comment: Can you provide a picture of the modification please..it will help me a lot.

Comment: Sure :) Look at my updated post. Hope this helps.

Comment: You have the eye of a vulture! Great find! Had the exact same issue, couldn't make the boards work until I removed that darn capacitor. These Chinese components are cheap, but come with some surprise headaches.